# Convert number stored as text to value in multiple sheets with same range

Tags: excel, vba

My question today is simple but hard for excel novice like me. I have two worksheets called Sales and Pipeline which has same headings so the range is same, i want to convert the numbers stored as text as values simultaneously in both the sheets, the numbers as text are present in Column I and Column Y, i have used the below code but am not able to find the method to activate the pipeline sheet and also the current code changes all the values from I to Y as values which is not required,

```
Sub ConvertNumber()
    Dim rng As Range

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Activate

    Range("I2:I10000", "Y2:Y10000").Select
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value

    End With
    MsgBox "Company ID and DUNS Number Converted to Values"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using 2 loops:

```
Sub marine()
    For Each s In Array("Sales", "Pipeline")
        For Each t In Array("I2:I10000", "Y2:Y10000")
            With Sheets(s).Range(t)
                .NumberFormat = "General"
                .Value = .Value
            End With
        Next t
    Next s
End Sub
```

Comment: Which is basically what i did, and apparently does not work for OP.

Comment: @ScottCraner  Why yes, it IS basically the same.................both our codes should work unless there is some other issue, like a Protection problem, but then we would get an error message.

Comment: Hello Gary, this also works, thanks much for the time

Answer (score 1):

Split it into two subs and call it twice:

```
Sub Main()
    ConvertNumber ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sales")
    ConvertNumber ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pipeline")
    MsgBox "Company ID and DUNS Number Converted to Values"
End Sub

Sub ConvertNumber(MySheet As Worksheet)
    With MySheet.Range("I2:I10000", "Y2:Y10000")
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: change `"I2:I10000", "Y2:Y10000"` to `"I2:I10000,Y2:Y10000"` or it will do all the columns between I and Y not just those two.

Comment: @AntiDrondert is this the full code? it say Argument not optional

Comment: @VenusExcel it is, you run the first not the second.  The second is called by the first.

Comment: @Scott Craner i did try this earlier but i find a vague issue, a single number "2377161" which is first number in Column I get copied to all the rows in column Y

Comment: @VenusExcel yes, I have seen that happen as well.  You will need to split the ranges then into two separate procedures.

Comment: @ScottCraner how do i do it, am still not yet a master in VBA

Comment: Hello Antidrondert: This is works well, thanks much for time

Comment: @VenusExcel Sorry for not answering, didn't have means to do it. Hope everything resolved nicely.

Answer (score 0):

This uses arrays and loops through those:

```
Sub ConvertNumber()
    Dim shtArr As Variant
    Dim rngArr As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    shtArr = Array("Sales", "Pipeline")
    rngArr = Array("I2:I10000", "Y2:Y10000")
    For i = LBound(shtArr) To UBound(shtArr)
        For j = LBound(rngArr) To UBound(rngArr)
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(shtArr(i)).Range(rngArr(j))
                .NumberFormat = "General"
                .Value = .Value
            End With
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: i just copy pasted this code and the excel quickly goes into still, as if nothing happened with the sheet

Comment: not sure why, it works for me, did you see the edit, where I fixed the column y reference?

Comment: @VenusExcel you can only choose one of the answers as correct, choose the one that you ended up using.